# Timezone of session in rest framework

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, django-rest-framework

In the [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) using date/time data, exists some way to auto convert this infos for the client timezone?

I'm saving this data in DB as UTC-0, and for each request using that, I need to convert date/time for the client timezone.

What's the best way to keep the client timezone stored, like in sessions with django, and convert date/time in serializers, maybe overriding the `serializers.DateTimeField` or something similar to this?